# Google people API not able to fetch emailAddresses

Tags: go, google-people-api

I am writing a desktop app that needs to authenticate a google user and fetch his email id. So far with the quickstart example, I am able to authenticate but I am having a hard time fetching user email address.

```
config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, people.UserEmailsReadScope)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
}
client := getClient(config)

srv, err := people.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(client))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to create people Client %v", err)
}
me, err := srv.People.Get("people/me").PersonFields("emailAddresses").Do()

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve user. %v", err)
}
```

I also tried UserinfoEmailScope but no luck. Getting 403 each time.

```
googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission to request "people/me". Request requires one of the following scopes: [profile]., forbidden
```

I have added all of these scopes to the project also. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. Two scopes are required for this.

```
config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, people.UserinfoProfileScope, people.UserinfoEmailScope)
```